# Simulating Diffusion/Wiener Process with Random Walk

Tags: matlab, random-variable, random-walk

I hope this is the right section for this kind of questions.

I am trying to simulate, with MATLAB, a diffusion model starting from a Random Walk. 
I am using a Random Walk with information increment X normally distributed ($\mu, \sigma$ ).
I also have a boundary $\alpha $, and $\alpha > \mu$.  The starting point is 0.

If I understood this right, this should be an approximation of the Wiener Process. 
As wikipedia says (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution), 
the first passage time for a fixed level $\alpha > 0 $by $X_t$ is distributed according to an inverse-gaussian:
$
    T_\alpha = \inf\{ 0 < t \mid X_t=\alpha \} \sim IG(\tfrac\alpha\nu, \tfrac {\alpha^2} {\sigma^2}).\, $

What I am trying to do is to simulate a Random Walk and to get the first passage time distribution, verifying that it is actually a Inv. Gaussian with those parameters.

This is the code I have done: http://pastebin.com/E1N58sJ4

Notice that the myHist function is commented, but I normally use it: in that function I fit the resulting distribution to an inverse gaussian. Then I compare the fitted parameters with the two parameters obtained by the formula showed above, $\mu= \alpha/v $ and $ \lambda= \alpha^2/\sigma^2 $

However, the two results are NOT THE SAME, and they differ consistently across simulation. 
For example, with the parametrers used in the code:

Simulation - mu:29.1771 s:  116.7757
Expected - mu:26.3158 s:  100

This difference is consistent across repetition of simulation.

Can anyone spot the mistake?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was already asked on the math site

Comment: I already flagged it to a moderator. I first opened it here, and then I realized it was better suited for math exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses a quite low sampling rate ($\Delta t = 1$) for simulating the Wiener process. Consider a case where the process crosses the boundary but then returns back to below $\alpha$ before the next sample. This causes $T_\alpha$ to be overestimated, as the first noticed boundary-crossing will occur later than the actual first boundary-crossing.

Indeed, by modifying your code to use $\Delta t = 0.01$, I got a mean of simulated $T_\alpha$s much closer to the analytically obtained 26.3. (I did not check the other parameter as you did not describe how you fit the distribution).

Comment: Hi Juho, thank you for your answer. How would you actually implement that?
By the way, I fit the distribution with a Max. Lik. Est.